# Which files are cached by linux?

Tags: linux, memory, cache, kernel, memory-management

I understand that linux uses unused RAM to keep some files cached. But I wonder, which files it actually caches! If you take a look at `free` :

```
Gesamt Belegt Frei Gemeinsam Puffer Cached
Speicher:       5,8G       3,7G       2,1G         0B       259M       1,7G
-/+ Puffer/Cache:       1,8G       4,0G
Auslagerungsdatei:       4,0G         0B       4,0G
```

it says that 1.7 GB of my RAM are used as a cache. I know that this is not harmful behavior, but I am curious about which files Linux considers to be cache-worthy. Is there a command/a file that shows me the cached files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, the Linux kernel caches *specific pages* of a file, i.e. not the entire file is loaded into the page cache. One tool which you can use to figure out whether *some* contents of a file is in the page cache is `fincore` from the [`linux-ftools`](http://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/) project. While it doesn't display all the cached files on disk, it gives you a rough idea of what is loaded into the page cache.

An example (quoted from the project's website):

```
root@xxxxxx:/var/lib/mysql/blogindex# fincore --pages=false --summarize --only-cached * 
stats for CLUSTER_LOG_2010_05_21.MYI: file size=93840384 , total pages=22910 , cached pages=1 , cached size=4096, cached perc=0.004365 
stats for CLUSTER_LOG_2010_05_22.MYI: file size=417792 , total pages=102 , cached pages=1 , cached size=4096, cached perc=0.980392 
stats for CLUSTER_LOG_2010_05_23.MYI: file size=826368 , total pages=201 , cached pages=1 , cached size=4096, cached perc=0.497512 
stats for CLUSTER_LOG_2010_05_24.MYI: file size=192512 , total pages=47 , cached pages=1 , cached size=4096, cached perc=2.127660 
stats for CLUSTER_LOG_2010_06_03.MYI: file size=345088 , total pages=84 , cached pages=43 , cached size=176128, cached perc=51.190476 
stats for CLUSTER_LOG_2010_06_04.MYD: file size=1478552 , total pages=360 , cached pages=97 , cached size=397312, cached perc=26.944444 
stats for CLUSTER_LOG_2010_06_04.MYI: file size=205824 , total pages=50 , cached pages=29 , cached size=118784, cached perc=58.000000 
stats for COMMENT_CONTENT_2010_06_03.MYI: file size=100051968 , total pages=24426 , cached pages=10253 , cached size=41996288, cached perc=41.975764 
stats for COMMENT_CONTENT_2010_06_04.MYD: file size=716369644 , total pages=174894 , cached pages=79821 , cached size=326946816, cached perc=45.639645 
stats for COMMENT_CONTENT_2010_06_04.MYI: file size=56832000 , total pages=13875 , cached pages=5365 , cached size=21975040, cached perc=38.666667 
stats for FEED_CONTENT_2010_06_03.MYI: file size=1001518080 , total pages=244511 , cached pages=98975 , cached size=405401600, cached perc=40.478751 
stats for FEED_CONTENT_2010_06_04.MYD: file size=9206385684 , total pages=2247652 , cached pages=1018661 , cached size=4172435456, cached perc=45.321117 
stats for FEED_CONTENT_2010_06_04.MYI: file size=638005248 , total pages=155763 , cached pages=52912 , cached size=216727552, cached perc=33.969556 
stats for FEED_CONTENT_2010_06_04.frm: file size=9840 , total pages=2 , cached pages=3 , cached size=12288, cached perc=150.000000 
stats for PERMALINK_CONTENT_2010_06_03.MYI: file size=1035290624 , total pages=252756 , cached pages=108563 , cached size=444674048, cached perc=42.951700 
stats for PERMALINK_CONTENT_2010_06_04.MYD: file size=55619712720 , total pages=13579031 , cached pages=6590322 , cached size=26993958912, cached perc=48.533080 
stats for PERMALINK_CONTENT_2010_06_04.MYI: file size=659397632 , total pages=160985 , cached pages=54304 , cached size=222429184, cached perc=33.732335 
stats for PERMALINK_CONTENT_2010_06_04.frm: file size=10156 , total pages=2 , cached pages=3 , cached size=12288, cached perc=150.000000 
---
total cached size: 32847278080
```

The command above lists some of the *.MYD, *.MYI and *.frm files that have some pages stored in the page cache.

If you really wanted to find out all files with at least 1 page in the page cache, this may work (untested, will produce large output and will probably take very long to run):

```
cd /
find . -type f | xargs fincore --pages=false --summarize --only-cached
```